# How to keep labels of a factor variable after transforming it to numeric in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data with three main variables:

i)  education (factor): represents three different level of education(1, 2, 3)

ii) share (numeric): represents the % of people in the country for each level of education

iii) country (factor): represents 30 countries.

The aim is to plot the share of education in each country by re_ordering the highest level of education (3) by countries that have the lowest share in it to the ones that have the highest. The issue is that i lose the country labels by the end because i have to transform the variable to numeric in order to reorder it. After plotting the graph, countries are labelled as (25, 6, 26, 17) instead of the correct labels (PT, CZ, RO, IT). I have read different threads in stackoverflow but non have solved the issue. I there a way to keep the labels of countries after re-ordering so i don't have to enter them manually later on?

```
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

 x$country = as.numeric(x$cntry2)
 x$educ = as.integer(x$educ)
 x$educ = as.factor(x$educ)
    
 country_order <- x %>% 
  filter(educ == 3) %>%
  mutate(country = fct_reorder(factor(country), share, .desc = FALSE)) %>% 
  pull(country) %>%
  levels()

df2 <- x %>%
  mutate(country = fct_relevel(factor(country), country_order))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=country, y=share)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill=educ), color = "black") +
  labs(fill= "Education") +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Country")
```

This is the data below:

```
structure(list(educ = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3"), class = "factor"), cntry2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L), .Label = c("AU", "BE", 
"BG", "CH", "CZ", "DK", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GR", "HU", "IE", 
"IS", "IT", "LT", "LU", "LV", "NL", "NO", "PO", "PT", "RO", "SE", 
"SK", "SV", "UK"), class = "factor"), share = c(14.9585723390695, 
64.8311026131294, 20.2103250478011, 20.3203525363306, 37.9050825638106, 
41.7745648998589, 20.5482068669118, 58.6719831908696, 20.7798099422186, 
11.0478359908884, 52.7334851936219, 36.2186788154898, 8.1806499751285, 
77.2156358812801, 14.6037141435914, 18.43684842358, 44.6831364124597, 
36.8800151639603, 13.0425889732285, 58.1996272896687, 28.7577837371029, 
42.6625051189251, 24.1934234264148, 33.1440714546602, 16.4821228232769, 
46.3050582898395, 37.2128188868836, 22.0117072122872, 47.7342785027657, 
30.2540142849471, 31.6958715347475, 40.8370856615852, 27.4670428036673, 
15.620426612099, 63.1486925776748, 21.2308808102263, 27.79203576455, 
33.4878715125424, 38.7200927229075, 29.0666986564299, 41.950575815739, 
28.9827255278311, 36.0270124068613, 47.1984225312789, 16.7745650618598, 
8.20398339670027, 60.9892218075273, 30.8067947957724, 37.0050817095017, 
37.4766935985084, 25.5182246919899, 15.7399902739504, 59.1482759419216, 
25.111733784128, 19.2624176167015, 43.4944817814291, 37.2431006018693, 
17.6501727404436, 44.6784798840967, 37.6713473754597, 10.0098831213475, 
69.2849776555517, 20.7051392231007, 64.5019644095216, 21.5391726369309, 
13.9588629535475, 21.8434913468774, 62.6661650363682, 15.4903436167545, 
11.4840104928012, 55.3435190932938, 33.172470413905, 4.23006072183939, 
74.1147574537763, 21.6551818243843, 15.6869892409901, 61.3851490387442, 
22.9278617202657, 14.2357801080394, 49.3703276303246, 36.393892261636
), country = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 14, 
14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 
19, 20, 20, 20, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 
26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30)), row.names = c(NA, 
-81L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tropical approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
x$lab <- as.character(x$cntry2)
x$country = as.numeric(x$cntry2)
x$educ = as.integer(x$educ)
x$educ = as.factor(x$educ)
```

Now, we store the labels:

```
#Labels
labs <- x[!duplicated(x$country),]
labs <- labs[,c('country','lab')]
```

Then more data process:

```
#Data
country_order <- x %>% 
  filter(educ == 3) %>%
  mutate(country = fct_reorder(factor(country), share, .desc = FALSE)) %>% 
  pull(country) %>%
  levels()
df2 <- x %>%
  mutate(country = fct_relevel(factor(country), country_order))
```

And the plot:

```
#Plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x=country, y=share)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill=educ), color = "black") +
  labs(fill= "Education") +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Country")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=labs$lab[match(country_order,labs$country)])
```

Output:

[image]